# Too many requests issue in LoadRunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Hi I'm new to loadrunner.
I'm getting **HTTP Status-Code=429 (Too Many Requests)** in my script.
I'm giving think time in between requests but still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

"I am new to LoadRunner..."

Have you been through training and are you engaged with a mentor to deliver on your performance testing effort?

It is important to remember the client server model when putting together your test code.  It is predicated upon a delay between requests where the resources not in use by client A, are then used to service Clients B through Z.  There is a natural ebb and flow to requests as the person in the chair at the client end reads, processes, and responds to the application prompts.   As you collapse the time outside of a natural range you run into a model violation which makes your test less of a predictor of what is to happen in production.

Your 429 Status is likely occurring because you are rate limited due to overdriving a site.  This can occur on public facing sites when people use automatied tools to drive load.   Is this a site you own and manage or is this a site such as Google search that you were experimenting with?